# Select Date By Year in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I've got a system built in CakePHP and one of the selection fields for the data is a year. Is there a simple way to put something into the condition array to match date on the selected year?

Comment: I think you need to provide a lot more details for anybody to be able to answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just going to go out on a limb and guess that your question is

> I have a date field in the database that stores dates like '2009-08-03'. How can I select all dates of 2009 using Cake?

In which case my answer would be that the simplest way is probably this:

```
$conditions = array(
    'Model.date >=' => "$year-01-01",
    'Model.date <=' => "$year-12-31"
);
```

[Mind Reader http://uvshock.co.uk/badges/badge.php?label=Mind%20reader&medal=bronze](http://uvshock.co.uk/badges/badge.php?label=Mind%20reader&medal=bronze)

Comment: It seems I was correct, awarding myself the Mind Reader badge. ;P

Answer (score 9):

In your find conditions use:

```
     $conditions = array('YEAR(Model.date)' => '2009');
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean `date("Y")`? See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php